how do I open a second main window in QTQuick 6.8 without app shutdown?
I'm using Qt Quick (v6.8). I open a second application window from my first application window. I then shutdown the first window. A few seconds later, my second window closes automatically, which is not what I want. I want my new window to show until the user closes it, triggering a full application shutdown only then. I load my main window, which is defined in QML, via engine.loadFromModule("MainModule", "MainWindow"); in my main func. I load the second window via this code from within the MainWindow.qml:
let component = Qt.createComponent("../../BoxModule/BoxWindow.qml")
if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
    let newWindow = component.createObject()
    newWindow.showMaximized()
    // WindowStore.secondWindow = newWindow // attempted to use singleton
    mainWindow.close()
}

What's the smarter way to do this? I made a singleton object that I used to hold the handle, thinking that would keep it in scope, but I must need something else too, as that didn't work. Does closing an ApplicationWindow automatically trigger a shutdown in QT6?

You can open several windows without problem. For some reason putting Windows inside a root item isn't enough since some Qt5 version. Once that worked but not in Qt6. So to show the window(s) some simple trick is required.
QtObject {
    property var wnd1: Window  {
        width: 640
        height: 480
        visible: true
        title: qsTr("Window 1")
    }
    property var wnd2: Window {
        width: 640
        height: 480
        visible: true
        title: qsTr("Window 2")
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        wnd1.show();
        wnd2.show();
    }
}


This sample code assumes that the containing QtObject will stay in scope, such that wnd1 and wnd2 stay in scope. How are you keeping it alive? I'm talking about a scenario where the object that shows the window goes out of scope immediately afterward. If that was to happen in this sample code, wnd1/2 would be garbage-collected and closed/destroyed.

What do you mean by saying "goes out of scope"? Can you provide a scenario?
